# Google Maps API Results

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I search for "ankara polis karakolları" on maps.google.com and google returned me more than 10  results as seen from the link:

http://tinyurl.com/cssna5v

When I use this link http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=ankara+polis+karakollar%C4%B1&sensor=true to get the same result, I can only get 10 results which is same as the number of results shown on google maps page

Is there a way of getting all the search results using Google Maps API ?

Answer (score 0):

The results on maps.google.com are different from those returned by the geocoder, they include other search results as well ("Places", see the [Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/) and others).

Also (for what it is worth) see this [entry in the FAQ](https://developers.google.com/maps/faq#geocoder_differences)

Comment: I tried Google Places API by using the ling below with my key:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/xml?query=restaurants+in+Sydney&sensor=true&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

and I got this:

<PlaceSearchResponse>
<status>REQUEST_DENIED</status>
</PlaceSearchResponse>

Comment: Did you enable the places API for that key?

Comment: Yes, this link with my places API works without any problem:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=